# SWIFT 2 : Problems with the first swipe gesture on a MapView

Tags: ios, swift2, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a issue with my swipe gesture on a MapView, to be more accurate I have issues with the first swipe gesture on a MapView because it does not does a function & moves the screen at the same time.

- The code recognize my location, put an annotation on me, and runs a 5 sec timer that allows the app to add new annotations only every 5 secs. The MapView follows my path as usually. All good so far. Check the pic of my simulator at the end.

Then it occurred to me that it would be a good idea to allow the user to scape from that region and explore the rest of the map. The user can do that only swiping in any direction. And when the user is at any other location he can press the "getBack" button to center the map on his current location. All works good too.

The issue is that when the gesture Swipe is detected , that first swipe does not move the screen. It is only the second swift which does it. 
I think that may be the first swipe only stops the map from following my path, and then the second one is the one that moves the screen.
Is there a way for the first swipe to stop following my path and move the map at the same time ?

- I hope I made myself clear :(

The Code of the ViewController:

```
import UIKit

import MapKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

var reStartCountClock = true

var getBackInPlace = true

var timer = NSTimer()

@IBAction func getBack(sender: AnyObject) {

getBackInPlace = true

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

locationManager.delegate = self

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "actionWhenPressed:")

uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1

map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)

let uilpgrD = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleSwipe:"))

uilpgrD.direction = .Down

let uilpgrU = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleSwipe:"))

uilpgrU.direction = .Up

let uilpgrR = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleSwipe:"))

uilpgrR.direction = .Right

let uilpgrL = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleSwipe:"))

uilpgrL.direction = .Left

map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgrD)

map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgrR)

map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgrL)

map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgrU)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

let locationOnline:CLLocation = locations[0]

let spanOnline:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)

let centerOnline:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationOnline.coordinate.latitude, locationOnline.coordinate.longitude)

let regionOnline:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerOnline, spanOnline)

if getBackInPlace == true {

self.map.setRegion(regionOnline, animated: true)

}

if reStartCountClock == true {

timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "Anota", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

reStartCountClock = false

let annotationOnline = MKPointAnnotation()

annotationOnline.title = "Updated Location"

annotationOnline.subtitle = "Pin Pam Pum"

annotationOnline.coordinate = centerOnline

self.map.addAnnotation(annotationOnline)

}

}

func handleSwipe (gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)

{

getBackInPlace = false

print("Entra en el gesto")

}

func Anota (){

reStartCountClock = true

timer.invalidate()

}

func actionWhenPressed (gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began

{

getBackInPlace = false

print("Gesture Recognized")

let touch = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.map)

let touchCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = map.convertPoint(touch, toCoordinateFromView: self.map)

let touchAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

touchAnnotation.coordinate = touchCoordinate

touchAnnotation.title = "You tapped here"

touchAnnotation.subtitle = "It is a recommended place"

self.map.addAnnotation(touchAnnotation)

}

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

}
```

The Simulator:

[image: Swift 2 - Swipe Gesture On Maps]